# Problems installing Directus - Cannot install: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1709 Index column size too large"

Tags: directus

I am trying to install Directus on a managed dedicated server and hit some issues. The error is:
Cannot install: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1709 Index column size too large"
And this is displayed on the last step of the setup.
I followed this report: https://github.com/directus/api/issues/942 and spoke to our sysadmin.
Seems like it's a MariaDB 10.1 bug. This will be upgraded but not right away as the machines are managed. The best fix at the moment according to them would be to alter the row format (from COMPACT, to either COMPRESSED or DYNAMIC) of all of the tables in the database. This needs to be set to the individual tables in the db when they're created.
This is not an option however as the problem comes mid-install, and requires the tables to be dropped for the install to be re-attempted. 
Is there something that could potentially be changed in the install script to set this row format on DB creation?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help?

https://github.com/directus/api/issues/942

> upgrading MariaDB to version 10.3 fixes this problem
>
> upgrading MySQL to version 5.7 fixes this problem